# How to forward range of ports in FreeBSD

Tags: nat, port-forwarding, asterisk

I am trying to configure asterisk PBX behind my FreeBSD router.
To allow other sip clients to call I need to forward ports to my local network asterisk machine.
I did it for 5060 and 5061 ports using ipnat and configuring ipnat.rules

```
rdr fxp0 217.199.MYIP.MYIP/32 port 5061 -> 192.168.1.7 port 5061 udp
```

But I do not know how I can redirect UDP port range from 60000 to 610000 and also port 
range UDP Port 10000 - 20000

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ill answer in to my question regard to others if will have similar problems

```
rdr fxp0 217.199.MYIP.MYIP/32 port 60000-61000 -> 192.168.1.7 port 60000 udp
```

Trick in the minus sing (-) where you can set range of ports,

Comment: You could also do: rdr fxp0 0/32 port 60000-61000 -> 192.168.1.7 port 60000 udp Wondering though why you want to do this, as this will shovel any connection inbound on fxp0 between 60000 an 61000 to port 60000 on 192.168.1.7 - which I think is your asterisk machine. You would be better off looking for a SIP Proxy to run on your FreeBSD machine that would intelligently open the media ports for your SIP connection - aas that is what you seem to want to be doing here?

Have a look at http://www.iptel.org/ser/

Comment: @ColtonCat I will try to install SER , Yes my asterisk machine is on 1.7 ip address and I did forwarding according to vopi-info.org 
If you can please repeat your comment as an answer so I can accept it as correct, And I if you can give me some basic points how I should configure SIP proxy and which mode to use in SER. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

With PF, you could do it with variables.

myports = "{ 22 25 2022 2222 8000 }"
rdr on $ext_if proto udp from any to $ext_if port $myports -> 192.168.1.7

...or something.

Comment: Probably this will work but how then I can fill my variable with  10000 values

Comment: I think you can make a range with a colon, 80:90 would be 80 through 90 for example. It should be in the pf.conf manpage.